# "Look around" subsetting function

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a data frame with clickstream data. I'm interested in what happened just before and just after certain events defined by a boolean expression involving multiple columns -- i.e., given a boolean expression, I would like to output a subset of the original data frame which includes 10 rows above and below each row satisfying the expression. Is there an elegant way of doing this, for example using dplyr?

Adding a reproducible example:

`df <- data.frame(col1 = c(rep("a",20), rep("b",20)), col2 = c(1:20, 1:20))`

`look_around(df, col1 == "a" & col2 %in% c(17,20))` should produce `df[7:30,]`

Write the function look_around.

Comment: You should provide some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output to make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a variation on `subset`, so I adapted the following from `subset`:

```
look_around <- function(data, condition, before=10, after=10) {
    # Set default values for `before` and `after` to 10
    e <- substitute(condition)
    r <- eval(e, data, parent.frame())
    rows <- unique(as.vector(sapply(which(r), function(x) {
        (x-before):(x+after)
    })))
    rows <- rows[rows > 0 & rows <= nrow(data)]
    data[rows,]
}
```

Output:

```
> df <- data.frame(col1 = c(rep("a",20), rep("b",20)), col2 = c(1:20, 1:20))
> look_around(df, col1 == "a" & col2 %in% c(17,20), before=10, after=10)
   col1 col2
7     a    7
8     a    8
9     a    9
<snip>
30    b   10
```

Comment: The OP might not know about setting default values in a function definition, so could show that as well, like `function(data, condition, before = 10, after = before)`